# unable to navigate to Destination View Controller in Storyboard in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, push

Hi I am using storyborad to create UI in IOS.eveything is fine but its not navigating to next view controller.I am using  code as below

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self]; and 

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier"]){

      ViewController *destVC =(ViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];

   }
```

My Tableview delegates

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InfoCell";


        HMSForumInfoCell *cell = (InfoCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            NSLog(@"Cell created");
        }


        NSDictionary *detailsDic = [_filteredListOfForums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        [cell.headLinesLabel setText:[detailsDic objectForKey:kTopic]];

         // Adding underlined Colored text using NSMutableAttributedString

        NSMutableAttributedString *commentString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[detailsDic objectForKey:kCreatedby]];


        UIColor* textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:198.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        [commentString setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:textColor,NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]} range:NSMakeRange(0,[commentString length])];

        [cell.nameButton setAttributedTitle:commentString forState:UIControlStateNormal];


   //     [cell.nameButton addTarget:self action:@selector(replyButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        [cell.nameButton addTarget:self action:@selector(namebuttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        [cell.replyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(replyButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



        return cell;
    }

    - (void)replyButtonPressed:(id)sender {


            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"id1" sender:self];

    }

    - (void)namebuttonPressed:(id)sender {


        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"id2" sender:self];


    }
```

Please correct me where am doing wrong.
**P.S:** I have connectd View Controller properly with segueIdentifier in story board and changed class name of VC to my Class.

Comment: Errors logged? Exceptions?

Comment: So what is the problem here? Please add some more information about your problem because now it's about impossible to answer.

Comment: Are you using a modal segue? If not, do you definitely have a navigation controller in the storyboard

Comment: check your segue identifier name, is it matching with the segue name? maybe you are using storyboard viewcontroller identifier name for segue

Comment: i checked my segue name also .Control is coming to the next view controller viewdidload and tableview delegated the problem is its not showing the next view controller @suhit

Comment: am not getting any exception and crash and all @Wain

Comment: why you are calling the method [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self]; if you are creating the segue in storyboard you don't need to call performsegue, just control drag say from button or tableviewcell to nextviewcontroller and when you click the button segue will happen automatically

Comment: In my button action only @suhit

Comment: - (void)namebuttonPressed:(id)sender {
    
    
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self];
    
    
}

Comment: if you create segue from button to nextviewcontroller, you don't need to use performsegue and prepareforsegue, it will happen automatically

Comment: yes thanks @suhit but am using table view cell button action thats need preparesegue and all right?

Comment: could you add code for cellforRowAtIndexPath: method

Comment: sure and thanks for your effort @suhit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41761/discussion-between-sugan-s-and-suhit)

Comment: if i present as Modal its working fine if am presenting as push its not working @suhit i think might be navigatinon controller issue.if possible can u help me

Comment: have you embedded your viewcontroller in uinavigationcontroller?

Comment: Hi @suhit thanks for your help.Now its working i just removed all connection and did again its working.but i didn't know y?

Comment: great to hear it's working, maybe some connections were missing earlier.

Comment: Thank you so much friend @suhit.I struggled for more than 4 hrs.

Answer (score 1):

This code will be really useful to you to change the view controller using Storyboard ID.

For example -
There were 2 view Controllers named FirstViewController and SecondViewController respectively.
If you want to move from FirstViewController to SecondViewController there is a simple Code using Storyboard  ID.

**Step 1 :-**

Enter the StoryBoard ID for both the ViewControllers

**Step 2 :-**

Write a code in FirstViewController -

```
let secondVC =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in performSegueWithIdentifier actually does nothing. So to show the destination scene you must wire it in Interface Builder like so:

- Embed the first scene in a navigation controller (menu: Editor / Embedd / Navigation Controller)
- Create the second scene
- create a control on the first scene that triggers the second scene
- Wire (Ctrl-Drag) the control from the first scene to the second scene
- On "mouse button up" the pop up menu select the option "push" from the segue

Then it should look like this and should work:

[image]

Hope this helps.